# Adding up values in text boxes of MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in access that has several text boxes `(text1, text2, text3)` with different numbers.

I want to be able sum all the values of the text boxes and display the total on a "total" text box.

I have tried

```
total = Text1.Value + Text2.Value = Text3.Value
```

it did not work.

I have also tried

```
total = Nz(Sum([Text1,Text2,Text3]), 0)
```

and it also does not work.

Comment: Eh... Have you tried `total = Text1.Value + Text2.Value + Text3.Value`? That seems the most obvious way to me.

Comment: Here's a tutorial from Microsoft you could check out: [**"Introduction to expressions"**](https://support.office.com/article/introduction-to-expressions-5cad6e24-65a3-4a95-82cc-92b4b1bd4b8b).

Comment: eh yes I have, it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
total = Nz([Text1],0) + Nz([Text2],0) + Nz([Text3],0)
```

You have to check for each individual textbox to not be null. If they are not locked to only allow numbers you also need validation for non-numerical input.

Answer (score 0):

specify the *ControlSource* of the Total textbox like this:

```
=[Text1]+[Text2]+[Text3]
```